# CreateUserWizard can't send email (via gmail) due SmtpClient.SslStream being set to false

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-membership, smtp

I’d like for *CreateUserWizard* control to send email notifications to created users.
Since I don’t host my own SMTP server, I tried to use my gmail account to send those notifications, but I kept getting “*Must issue STARTTLS command first*”. One site suggests this is due to CreateUserWizard’s SmtpClient using  *System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream*
and not *System.Net.Security.SslStream*.

Thus only way I know how to configure *CreateUserWizard* control to send emails (via gmail) is by handling *SendingMail* event, where I have to cancel the event ( via  *MailMessageEventArgs.Cancel*) and then manually create and send the email ( that way I'm able to set *SmtpClient.EnableSsl* to *true* ).

Is there a way to get a reference to *CreateUserWizard's SmtpClient* object and set its *EnableSsl* to *true* so that i don't have to manually send email notifications?

thanx

Answer (score 2):

I am affraid there is no other solution...
There is a [Suggestion](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=281277) on microsoft site for adding EnableSSL direcly to the smtp config...
Until that the workaround is:

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_OnSendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
{
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.Send(e.Message);
e.Cancel = true;
}
```